# php variable reset to 0

Tags: php, variables

A php variable $a (which was set to a value earlier in the code) is being reset to a value of 0 and I don't want it to.  At the end of the php code, I did an echo and $a was 0.  So I made a debugging array to catch the value at various points.  I found where it's getting set to 0.  Here's the code:

```
$a = 1;
if($total> 0){  
  $a = ($a/$total);  
  $X["i"]=$a;    
}
$X["ii"]=$a;  

Output:
$x["i"]=1;
$x["ii"]=0;
```

A few things:
There are no functions at all (and obviously not where it's being set to 0), and $a is a global.
It's a very large php file.  I'm wondering if memory is the problem...?  No idea.
I'm not a nube to php, or to programming.

Comment: that could couldn't do such a thing, unless `$a` is a reference established elsewhere in code you haven't shown, meaning it can change values unpredictably based on actions elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Perhaps somewhere else in the code you're using what you think is a different variable called `$a` (assuming that's it's real name, which is a very bad name for a variable) and over-writing it accidentally?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting capital X and outputting lower case x

(If this was just a typo, please show more code. For example the outputting code.)

Comment: That was just a typo re: the x vs X.  One more thing: there could very well have been a division-by-zero error prior to the code I showed with the variable at some point (fyi: I didn't show all my code because it's really huge).  So still nothing could have happened in the code shown, but could a prior math error be to blame?

Comment: @user2278448 only if you are doing stuff between setting $x['i'] and $x=['ii']. What you have shown contains no obvious error. So you need to throw us a bit more to be able to help you. You can try putting the code on pastebin, if its too big for here.